# Receiving MMS programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How can I make my app be able to receive MMS? I am developing one app that should receive MMS. In other words my app should be able to read MMS.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure that's not possible unless you're writing for jailbroken phones...

Comment: but cant i hv whatsup app like functionality in my app

Comment: WhatsApp uses its own servers for that functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure what the connection is. You can't do it because iOS doesn't give you programmatic access to incoming MMS. Or SMS. Or phone calls. Or, in general, any notification which is not specifically intended for your app.